# Google sheets - Condition formatting using OR criteria based on multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm looking to highlight a number of cells using conditional formatting based on the value of another cell which I've got working using

```
A2:A995
=search("Eaten",$B:$B)
```

I'm trying to extend this to pick up all other columns as that match the same search criteria trying the below

```
A2:A996,C2:C995,E:E995 
=search("Eaten",$B:$B,$D:$D,$F:$F)
=OR(search("Eaten",$B:$B),search("Eaten",$D:$D)
```

It would be good if someone can point me in the right direction for this

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZVTlrexlInAuP3YLfpm-n98716DwKsKDUb-lQ6d8Fdg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: updated the sheet to public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

custom formula: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B1:H="Eaten", 1))`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this instance you can just use

```
=b2="Eaten"
```

as the custom formula and the rest follows by relative addressing.

[image]

[image]